# Reporting Services extract single values from dataset

Tags: reporting-services

Writing a Reporting Service (2005) report

My DataSet returns something like this:

```
DESCRIPTION       COUNT
Total Properties  12345
Demolished         1243
Non-Demolished    11102
  :
  :
```

I have this displayed as a table and this is fine.

Now I also want to display the data like this:

```
                     [ 12345 ] Total Properties
                       /   \
                     /       \
 Non-Demolished [ 11102 ]   [ 1243 ] Demolished
```

I can add the text-boxes and lines but what expression do I need to fill in the values?
Need somethig that returns the count based on a match to the description in the row.

Comment: How do you establish the parent-child relationship? It may be better to rotate the dataset into one row: (Total, Demolished, NonDemolished).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way to do it.

First(Fields!FieldName.Value,"DataSetName")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

=Iif(Fields!Description.Value = "Demolished", Fields!Count.Value, "Value not found")

Comment: But the text-boxes do not point to the DataSet so I can't reference any fields directly...

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean.  If your table can access the DataSet, your Textboxes should also be able to.

Comment: The text-boxes are not in a table. Perhaps they need to be?

Comment: I use textboxes all the time, and they work with the dataset specified in the RDL file.